# removing same fetched data php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","final_osa");
$s_stud = $con->query("SELECT * FROM violations_tbl GROUP BY violation_type");
while($data = $s_stud->fetch_assoc() ){
    $bilang = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM violations_tbl WHERE `violation_type` ='".$data['violation_type']."' ");
    $result = $bilang->fetch_assoc();
    if($result['COUNT(*)'] > 1 ){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                $query=$con->query("SELECT `violation_type` FROM `violations_tbl` WHERE `violation_type`='".$data['violation_type']."'");
                while($row=$query->fetch_assoc() ){
                    echo $row['violation_type'].", ";
                }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
    }
} 
?>
```

How can i eliminate same fetched data and echo only one? thanks

here is the one that it echoes. it should be that it will echo only one because its the same[image]

What i'm trying to do here is get the mos violated rule in school thanks

Comment: Can you show what you actually want reported please.

Comment: I want to report the violations of students and i want to know whats the most violated rule

Comment: Show us the output you want

Comment: Just remove the while loop. It is fetching all the values. and try changing the echo statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the violations in order of most violated to least violated

```
$s_stud = $con->query("SELECT violation_type, count(violation_type) as num_violations
                      FROM violations_tbl 
                      GROUP BY violation_type
                      ORDER BY num_violations DESC");

while($row= $s_stud->fetch_assoc() ){
    //echo the violation and the count
    if($row['num_violations'] > 1 ){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$row[violation_type]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[num_violations]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

If you only want the MOST violated you could add a `LIMIT 1` to the query and remove the looping.

```
$s_stud = $con->query("SELECT violation_type, count(violation_type) as num_violations
                      FROM violations_tbl 
                      GROUP BY violation_type
                      ORDER BY num_violations DESC
                      LIMIT 1");

$row= $s_stud->fetch_assoc();
//echo the violation and the count
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$row[violation_type]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[num_violations]</td>";
echo "</td></tr>";
```